# Update combobox in WPF based on input from textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

This should be a simple task, but I can't seem to get it right...

Ok, so I have this dialog which has 2 `textboxes` and 1 `combobox`. The `combobox` had 4 possible values (items): `"", AAA, BBB, CCC`.

What I want to achieve is this:
When something is written into textbox1 (`tbx1`) then the possible values of the `combobox` must be limited to: `"", BBB, CCC`.
When something is written into textbox2 (`tbx2`) then the possible values of the `combobox` must be limited to:`"", AAA, CCC`.
If input in both `tbx1` and `tbx2` is deleted, then all 4 values should be present in the `combobox` once again.

To detect whether something has been written into a tbx, I use the TextChanged event:

```
TextChanged="tbx1_TextChanged" for tbx1
TextChanged="tbx2_TextChanged" for tbx2
```

In the codebehind XAML file:
The list with the values `("", AAA, BBB, CCC)` comes from the Model. `List<string>` list.
I wrap into an `ObservableCollection`:

```
ListForComboboxItems= new ObservableCollection<string>(itsVm.list);
        ListForComboboxItems.CollectionChanged += ListForComboboxItems_CollectionChanged;
```

In the event handler for `tbx1` I have:

```
    private void tbx_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbx1.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbx1.Text))
        {
            if (!ListForComboboxItems.Contains("AAA"))
            {
                ListForComboboxItems.Add("AAA");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ListForComboboxItems.Contains("AAA"))
            {
                ListForComboboxItems.Remove("AAA");
            }
        }
    }
```

So what I would expect is that the `combobox` gets updated with only 3 `("", BBB, CCC)`. This does not happen. Why is this? It is like an event needs to be fired or something.

The reason I use the `ObservableCollection` is that it has the `CollectionChanged` event, which I've tried using but I must be doing something wrong in the `ListForComboboxItems_CollectionChanged` handler, because I get an error that the collection is already in use.

```
private void ListForComboboxItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var action = e.Action;
        if (action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var olditem in e.OldItems)
                {
                    var item = olditem.ToString();
                    this.ComboDropDownBox.Items.SourceCollection.Remove(item);  
                }
            }
        }

        if (action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            this.ComboDropDownBox.Items.Add(e.NewItems);
        }
}
```

Please point out the mistakes I've made, and help me find the right solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really want your textboxes to be bound to your VM and then have the VM update the source of your combobox appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Data binding is very much going to be your saviour here.  No need to implement the ListForComboboxItems_CollectionChanged event, the binding of the observable collection to the comboboxes itemssource will sort that for you.

Bind each textbox text property to a string dependency property then modify the collection when the property changes via a PropertyChangedCallback.  Alternatively you could look at something like a listviewcollection and filter the combobox itemssource.

Have a look round on this site for many examples of how to bind observable collections to comboboxes.